# Big EXE File in CDN why don't Become effective

Tags: cdn

I set expires 1h in nginx config.

this exe file size is 40M.

CDN always show MISS in CDN-XXX

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Pull zone most probably the provider wont cache files above a certain file-size. 

Most of them provide Push zones for big files.